# Native SQL Server JSON consumption failing

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am attempting to consume a JSON API and drop it into a table in SQL server (version 15.x). I can run it manually and it happily runs along and places nicely with my process.

I need to automate it to consume the API for archival needs, but when I dropped it into a SQL server Agent Job step and attempt to run it the thing fails with this message:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 16. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 13609).  The step failed.

So, that error message, when reviewing online, suggests that something is malformed in the JSON itself and I have no control over that. I do not know JSON very well and so have no clue what to do to fix the error.

Is my SQL wrong?
Is it appropriate to call it as a step in a Job as opposed to storing as a procedure and then calling the procedure? Does that matter?
The statement is below, it runs against a public API, so please test it and let me know what I did wrong!
Thanks

```
Declare @Object as Int;
DECLARE @hr  int
Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
               'https://seeclickfix.com/open311/v2/407/requests.json',
                 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
-- select the JSON string
select * from @json 
-- Parse the JSON string
insert into [DATA].[DATA].[SeeClickFix_APIFeed_refresh](
    [description]
    ,[address]
    ,[lat]
    ,[service_request_id] 
    ,[requested_datetime] 
    ,[long]
    ,[service code] 
    ,[status] 
    ,[zipcode] 
    ,[agency_responsible] 
    ,[service_name] 
    ,[media_url] 
    ,[expected_datetime] 
    ,[address_id]
    ,[service_notice] 
    ,[status_notes]
 ) 
SELECT *  FROM OPENJSON((select * from @json))
WITH (   
     [description] nvarchar(max) "$.description"   ,
        [address]   nvarchar(max) "$.address",
        [lat]   nvarchar(max) "$.lat",
        [service_request_id]   nvarchar(max) "$.service_request_id",
        [requested_datetime]   [nvarchar](max) "$.requested_datetime",
        [long]   nvarchar(max) "$.long",    
        [service code]   nvarchar(max) "$.service_code",
        [status]   nvarchar(max) "$.status",
        [zipcode]   nvarchar(max) "$.zipcode",
        [agency_responsible]   nvarchar(max) "$.agency_responsible",
        [service_name]   nvarchar(max) "$.service_name",     
        [media_url]  [nvarchar](max) "$.media_url",
        [expected_datetime]   [nvarchar](max) "$.expected_datetime",
        [address_id]   nvarchar(max) "$.address_id",
        [service_notice]   nvarchar(max) "$.service_notice",
        [status_notes]   nvarchar(max) "$.status_notes"     

)
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

I do not know that much about JSON and so not certain about what I can change to try to fix it

Comment: Please add to your question  JSON sample that is failing

Comment: Given the lack of meaningful error handling in the HTTP code (which you shouldn't be doing from T-SQL, by the way, those sp_OA methods are unreliable and lead to stability problems) are you sure you're even getting a JSON result from the remote service?

Comment: I would suggest to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74281242/edit) your question to remove the distracting code, showing us only your OPENJSON query along with the offending block of JSON data you received from the web service.

Comment: see, this is the problem! I have no solid knowledge of what I am doing here.   I found that above template online and it seems to be doing what I need it to do but do not know the back end of what it is and how it is working.   If I run that in ssms on its own I get the data as expected and it appends my table as expected. It fails when it is run in a SQL agent job.

Answer (score 0):

Got a fix for this, in its current state.
Some reviewers pointed out that this is a MS issue, not a json error.

Adding "SET TEXTSIZE -1" to the head allowed it to run in SQL Server Agent. It might have something to do with what the default textsize is on the server itself outside of SSMS.
Still not totally knowledgeable about what it is, and @alwaysLearning I need to learn more about your comment.